# FDR or log fold change: which one is the priority for selecting the DEGs?

Tags: r, biostatistics

I'm using DESeq2 Package in R for RNA-SEQ Analysis. Using Count Matrix. DE analysis is between two groups for eg: like Normal vs Tumor.

To select for the significant differential expression of genes in RNA-seq do I need to consider both FDR and log2FC (or) only FDR is fine?

When I consider the cutoff FDR < 0.05 & log2fc > 1/log2fc < 1, among 51539 I see 137 ~ Up-regulated and 540 ~ down-regulated genes

When I consider the cutoff only FDR < 0.05, among 51539 I see 6984 ~ Up-regulated and 7115 ~ down-regulated genes

And from these DE genes I wanted to filter lncRNAs based on lncRNA annotation.

So, which one is the priority for selecting the significant DEGs?

Answer (score 2):

If you think I misinterpret your question, please tell me. I'll edit my answer.

To me your question is:

> Should I use FDR or log-fold in my analysis?

Log-fold gives you the fold-change between the two conditions. You shouldn't use the magnitude of your LF to decide which gene is statistically differentiated because:

- It's just a number and thus no probability distribution, no p-value, no confidence interval, no null hypothesis and no inference.
- It's sensitive to lowly-expressed genes where the variability is high and thus your LF value might not be accurate.
- You don't "borrow" information from other similar abundant genes.
- What's the point of using DESeq2 if you just want to use log-fold? The point of DESeq2 is to estimate dispersion for your negative binomial model (because you have counting data).

You should use the FDR column. The FDR column gives you adjusted p-value (q-value) for each gene. Compare each q-value with your significance level.

**Note:** FDR and log-fold are two very different thing

Comment: Yes, What you said is right. But in some papers for RNA SEQ analysis I see that they used both q-value and log2FC to get significant genes. Andin some other they used only q-value to get significant genes. So, I'm confused in this part.

Comment: @user3351523 Do you have a paper? I'll take a read and edit my answer.

Comment: I have seen that in different research papers. Do you want me to give that here?

Comment: @user3351523 Please share a link. I'll try to address your question as much as I can.

Comment: Significantly differential expression based on FDR < 1% [http://www.nature.com/articles/srep37821] See in the Results: Paragraph "Global changes of the lincRNA species in breast cancer" (Last second line)

Comment: Significantly Differential expression based on two criteria |log2FC| >1 and qvalue < 0.05 [http://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms14421] See in the Methods: Differential expression analysis (second paragragh)

Comment: @SmallChess you certainly need to look at both p-value and fold change. p-value is the significance of the test of different means. The fold change in DESeq is the effect size. In a biological context, it is the effect size that matters. However, if you see a large effect size on a test with no significance, you can't trust that fold change value. Thus you need both and should always report both. This is true _regardless_ of how critical authors and journal reviewers are. See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/238326/141304